# Subscriptions in Commerce Stripe

Tags: commerce

I use the Commerce Stripe module to make charges on my website, but I need to be able to subscribe through Stripe, and I have no idea how to do it. The charges I make and without problem but I would need someone to show me the way on how to change the charge to subscription through Commerce Stripe. Thank you.

Comment: Any news not this one? Please provide some kind of feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change existing charge to subscription. It is not a trivial task, but doable by using such modules as [Commerce Recurring](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring) or  [Commerce License](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license) and [Commerce License Billing](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license_billing).